# How to calculate a GPA from grades and credits?

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, group-by, aggregate-functions

I want to calculate a GPA for each student from grades and credits. I have executed something like this

```
SET GPA=(SELECT((t.grade*c.credits)/c.credits)
FROM Student s, Take t, Courses c
WHERE s.sid=t.sid and t.cid=c.cid)
```

It doesn't work. The Select query's result has a lot of rows. So I couldn't finish this. My tables are like these:

- take (sid, cid, grade)
- course (cid, credits)
- student (sid,gpa)

I'm using PostgreSQL.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include sample data for each table, as well as the output you're expecting to see from that sample data as a result of your query.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT s.sid, (SUM(t.grade * c.credits) / SUM(t.credits)) AS GPA
FROM Student s
INNER JOIN Take t ON s.sid = t.sid 
INNER JOIN Courses c ON t.cid = c.cid
GROUP BY s.sid
```

Comment: It is actually same with my code. It comes "sid"s and "gpa"s. But I want calculate gpa from grades and credits for each student. For example for no 1 student ; SET no1 GPA = no1.grade1*course1.credits + no1.grade2*course2.credits + ... / sum(no1.credits) (it's not code just like mathematical formula)